# How to include a source file that has modules

Tags: rust

I have a project structure similar to this:

```
gen/foo.rs
gen/foo/bar.rs
src/main.rs
```

`foo.rs`:

```
mod bar;
```

bar.rs is empty.

`main.rs`:

```
#[path = "../gen/foo.rs"]
mod foo;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

This produces:

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `bar`
 --> src/../gen/foo.rs:1:1
  |
1 | mod bar;
  | ^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: to create the module `bar`, create file "src/../gen/bar.rs" or "src/../gen/bar/mod.rs"
```

Which seems weird.
If I had this structure:

```
src/foo.rs
src/foo/bar.rs
src/main.rs
```

It would work. But if `foo.rs` is included, Rust searches for its submodules in `gen/` instead of `gen/foo`.

Is there any way to make this work without changing the files in `gen/`?

Answer (score 4):

That's because for nested modules only the path of the module one up is used. Effectively the path you point `rustc` to is treated as a path to a `mod.rs`. You can just use that file name for your module foo and everything works out:

Package layout:

```
gen/foo/mod.rs
gen/foo/bar.rs
src/main.rs
```

`src/main.rs`

```rust
#[path = "../gen/foo/mod.rs"]
mod foo;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to not change the files in `gen` (they're vendored in my case) but this seems to be the easiest approach, thank you!